# Storm build: Missing Artifacts

Tags: java, maven, clojure, apache-storm

I'm trying to build Storm from the source (both 0.96 and 1.0) and I got a maven build error saying that I'm missing (lots of) artifacts.

Since there are so many artifacts that are missing, I wonder if there are any faster way to restore my all these artifacts without manually download and attach them one by one (or possibly because my maven is not correctly installed).

Below is the error message. I'm using maven 3.0 and java 1.7, and I am on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
lexu@Zhenghe:~/apache-storm-0.9.6$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:maven-shade-clojure-transformer:jar:0.9.6
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 694, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 660, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.6
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 694, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 660, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:storm-starter:jar:0.9.6
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 694, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 660, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:storm-kafka:jar:0.9.6
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 694, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 660, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:storm-hdfs:jar:0.9.6
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 694, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 660, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:storm-hbase:jar:0.9.6
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 694, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.6, /home/lexu/apache-storm-0.9.6/pom.xml, line 660, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ line 694, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ line 660, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Storm
[INFO] maven-shade-clojure-transformer
[INFO] Storm Core
[INFO] storm-starter
[INFO] storm-kafka
[INFO] storm-hdfs
[INFO] storm-hbase
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Storm 0.9.6
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ storm ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.2.1:process (default) @ storm ---
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.5.1
[WARNING] Missing POM for jline:jline:jar:2.11
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.5.1
[WARNING] Missing POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.0.6
[WARNING] Missing POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.0.6
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.clojure:tools.nrepl:jar:0.2.3
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.clojure:tools.cli:jar:0.2.4
[WARNING] Missing POM for commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4
[WARNING] Missing POM for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4
[WARNING] Missing POM for commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1
[WARNING] Missing POM for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.3
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.2
[WARNING] Missing POM for commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5
[WARNING] Missing POM for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Storm ............................................. FAILURE [0.416s]
[INFO] maven-shade-clojure-transformer ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Storm Core ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-starter ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-kafka ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-hdfs ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-hbase ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.075s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 04 23:25:18 CDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.2.1:process (default) on project storm: Failed to resolve dependencies for one or more projects in the reactor. Reason: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.0.6
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.fasterxml.jackson.core -DartifactId=jackson-core -Dversion=2.0.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.fasterxml.jackson.core -DartifactId=jackson-core -Dversion=2.0.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) org.thnetos:cd-client:jar:0.3.6
[ERROR] 4) cheshire:cheshire:jar:4.0.3
[ERROR] 5) com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.0.6
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 2) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.5.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.5.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.5.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.5.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 3) jline:jline:jar:2.11
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=jline -DartifactId=jline -Dversion=2.11 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=jline -DartifactId=jline -Dversion=2.11 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) jline:jline:jar:2.11
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 4) com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.0.6
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat -DartifactId=jackson-dataformat-smile -Dversion=2.0.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat -DartifactId=jackson-dataformat-smile -Dversion=2.0.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) org.thnetos:cd-client:jar:0.3.6
[ERROR] 4) cheshire:cheshire:jar:4.0.3
[ERROR] 5) com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.0.6
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 5) org.clojure:tools.nrepl:jar:0.2.3
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=tools.nrepl -Dversion=0.2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=tools.nrepl -Dversion=0.2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) org.clojure:tools.nrepl:jar:0.2.3
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 6) org.clojure:tools.cli:jar:0.2.4
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=tools.cli -Dversion=0.2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=tools.cli -Dversion=0.2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) org.clojure:tools.cli:jar:0.2.4
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 7) commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-codec -DartifactId=commons-codec -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=commons-codec -DartifactId=commons-codec -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6
[ERROR] 4) ring:ring-core:jar:1.0.2
[ERROR] 5) commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 8) commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-io -DartifactId=commons-io -Dversion=2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=commons-io -DartifactId=commons-io -Dversion=2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6
[ERROR] 4) ring:ring-core:jar:1.0.2
[ERROR] 5) commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 9) commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-fileupload -DartifactId=commons-fileupload -Dversion=1.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=commons-fileupload -DartifactId=commons-fileupload -Dversion=1.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6
[ERROR] 4) ring:ring-core:jar:1.0.2
[ERROR] 5) commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 10) javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet -DartifactId=servlet-api -Dversion=2.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet -DartifactId=servlet-api -Dversion=2.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6
[ERROR] 4) ring:ring-core:jar:1.0.2
[ERROR] 5) javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 11) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.3
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.httpcomponents -DartifactId=httpclient -Dversion=4.3.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.httpcomponents -DartifactId=httpclient -Dversion=4.3.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6
[ERROR] 4) clj-http:clj-http:jar:0.3.6
[ERROR] 5) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.3
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 12) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.2
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.httpcomponents -DartifactId=httpmime -Dversion=4.1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.httpcomponents -DartifactId=httpmime -Dversion=4.1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 2) reply:reply:jar:0.3.0
[ERROR] 3) com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6
[ERROR] 4) clj-http:clj-http:jar:0.3.6
[ERROR] 5) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.2
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 12 required artifacts are missing.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR] org.apache.storm:storm:pom:0.9.6
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend running your build again with `-X` and `-e` switches as suggested in the error messages. I suspect there is some networking issue (e.g. your `settings.xml` configuring some incorrect proxy server or local repository mirror) preventing from accessing the artifacts as they do exist in the remote repositories (for example [`javax.servlet:servlet-api`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.servlet%7Cservlet-api%7C2.5%7Cjar)).

Comment: Oh I didn't realize we should use settings.xml in maven. I configured it based on http://central.sonatype.org/pages/consumers.html and everything works fine now. Thanks!